# bash script through docker cant cd into existing directory

Tags: bash, docker

I have a docker file 
which end with the following

```
COPY . /research

COPY ./funnel_viewer/run_dashboard.sh /
RUN chmod +x /run_dashboard.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/run_dashboard.sh"]
```

the run_dashboard.sh script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
  echo $(pwd)
  echo $(ls -l)
  cd ./funnel_viewer
  /opt/conda/envs/dashboard_env/bin/python dashboard.py run
```

When running the docker I get 'cant cd to funnel_viewer'
This is while the `echo ${ls -1}` shows directory exists.
Directories owner is root and so is user running the script.

Why am I getting the cand cd to.. error?

Comment: `/funnel_viewer` is an absolute path. If you need relative path use `./funnel_viewer`.

Comment: Yea - sorry, tried this before - still not working. Editing in question.   Problem yet exists, even when using relative path.

Comment: Can you delete this shell script, install packages into the "system" Python environment rather than creating a virtual environment, and use the Dockerfile `WORKDIR` and `CMD` directives instead?  That seems a little easier.  (Parenthetically, why `echo $(ls)` instead of just `ls`?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I found a workaround, using Docker's entrypoint instead of a bash script. Question remains the same, why did I get 'cant cd into X' while X exists.